# Why is my Axios request repeating when response time is slow

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a React front-end and a Flask back-end. On component mount in react, I make an Axios request to the back-end. The back-end does a SARIMAX algorithm forecast and returns the response.

This works perfectly fine 90% of the time, as long as the algorithm executes quickly. When my laptop gets hot, the algorithm takes longer to run, and when this happens the request is getting repeated. It just keeps on recalculating and the response never gets displayed.

This is not a deployed application, it is running on my localhost. I am not sure what is causing the difference in behavior. I have included the relevant React code from my component below

```
class Forecast extends React.Component {
    state = 
    {
        graphURL: "", 
        isLoading: true, 
        response: ""
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        Axios.get("/api/forecast",
        {
            headers:
            {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`
            }
        }).then(res =>
        {
            this.setState({graphURL: (res.data.success)})
            delete res.data.success;
            this.setState({response: (res.data), isLoading: false})
        })
    }

 

 render()
    {
        const {graphURL, isLoading} = this.state;
        if(isLoading)
        {
            return <div className="App">Loading...</div>;
        }

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="w3-container w3-center" style={{margin: "3rem"}}>
                    <h1 className="w3-jumbo">{this.state.isLoading}</h1>`enter code here`
                    <img alt="derp" src={this.state.graphURL} />
                    <JsonToTable json={this.state.responsey} />
                    <button type="button" className="w3-button w3-blue" onClick={() =>
                         window.location = "/"}>&laquo; Back</button> 

                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: could you check what happens when you remove that delete and last setState in componentDidMount and just do this.setState({graphURL: (res.data.success, response: (res.data), isLoading: false)})

Comment: I will try that and let you know, thank you for the suggestion. I had considered that setting state twice might have something to do with it, but was unsure why it would only cause a problem on a slow resopnse